# Как сделать минимальное количество вводимых символов в ckeditor?

Tags: ckeditor

Всем привет! Подскажите как сделать минимально вводимое количество символов в редакторе? Везде есть только ограничение по типу max_lenght, но например min_lenght нет такого.  Редактор у меня старый 13 го года помоему. Но в новой версии тоже не видел подобного.

Спасибо!

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: Здравствуйте, у меня на сайте стоит ckeditor текстовое поле, там стоит ограничение на 2000 символов, больше он не даст написать. Но бывает так что пользователи пишут всего пару слов а мне нужно что бы ckeditor имел минимально вводимое количество символов например 100, что бы меньше не вводили и соответственно не отправляли форму.